# How to update photo in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a gridview with employees name, there is link to another page,with employee information,when the user click on the link, according to employee id get the employee information from database, in this page we can add photos or update them,which works fine,

the problem is when updating the photo, and click the link, I see the same photo not the updates one,until I refresh the browser,

what is the solution for this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Same as http://forums.asp.net/t/1582648.aspx. Please also Edit your post there to include this url. People might be interested cross posts as well for answers in the future.

Comment: Also if you add a guid to the querystring of the image path like so:
src='/images/myImage.jpg?1234-23df22-32df3-df34' this will stop anyone's browser from caching the image.

Answer (score 0):

It seem sto be a cache problem. try to send a random param in the url to the next page where you see the Employees.
 Or try to put in the page where you see the employee information

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.No Cache)
Response.Cache.SetExpires(Now())
Response.AddHeader( "Pragma", "no-cache")
```

Hope it works